# Ctypes: [WinError 126] Cant find DLL

Tags: python, ctypes, 32bit-64bit

I know there are a lot of threads about the WinError 126 and so on. But I really need help...

I have a directory like this:

- mytestscript.py
- my32bit.dll
- my64bit.dll

I have a 32 Bit and a 64 Bit Python Interpreter installed.
Now if I run mytestscript.py with a 32 Bit Interpreter, everything works fine.

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("my32bit.dll")
print(dll)
```

But if i run it with a 64 Bit Interpreter

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("my64bit.dll")
print(dll)
```

I get the follwoing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Heinzeri/Desktop/TEMPY/mytestscript.py", line 4, in <module>
    dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("my64bit.dll")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37-64\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37-64\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

What could be the cause that the 64-Bit Python doesn't find the DLL?
Do I have to add it to PATH / PYTHONPATH?
Do I need some Microsoft Redistributable?

The DLL's are checked 64bit and 32bit and come from a vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could also mean that another dependency is missing. Please use [Dependencies](https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/) (successor of Dependency Walker) to check what is happening behind the scenes.

Maybe some runtime for 64-bit is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes the MSVCP110.dll was missing.
So I had suggesed the solution also right but I had the wrong version of the Microsoft distributables.